# Comparing numbers and making a calculation

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript I wrote for a recent work project that is essentially taking a `deviceorientation` event object, taking either the `beta` value or `gamma` value of that object and makes a calculation.

While I can't necessarily put my exact code here just in case that breaks any of the agreements I signed, the general idea is as follows. Just a note: this code is already headed for production and I'm not looking for someone to do my work for me. I'm asking this so I can use it for new code in the future. I like to keep functions small and avoid using complex structures like the one below, but my time in this field is still limited and I could not think of a better way to handle this.

The names of functions/variables have been changed to protect the identity of the innocent. I'm also skipping a few of the in between functions as I'm just wondering if there's a cleaner way to handle this calculation.

Code starts with adding an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', doSomeStuff, false);
```

`doSomeStuff` eventually makes a call to `makeCalculation` and passes along the event object:

```
function doSomeStuff(event){
    // Other stuff happens...
    makeCalculation(event);
}
```

At this point, I want to make a calculation based on the `beta` or `gamma` value of that event object. I have a minimum and maximum range I want stay within, as well as a slight alteration to the calculation when the value is between another range within the min-max range. I will use `event.gamma` as an example and ignore the logic to determine whether I want to use `beta` or `gamma`;

```
function makeCalculation(e){
    var value;    

    if (Math.round(e.gamma) === 0) {
        value = 0;
    } else if (e.gamma < -2) {
        value = // Some Calculation
    } else if (e.gamma > 2) {
        value = // Some Other Calculation
    } else {
        value = // Yet a different calculation 
    }

    return value;
}
```

Is there a better way to make number comparisons of this nature without having to creating a nasty looking `if`/`else if` block?

Comment: nothing can be done, if else is as per your requirement, This is a good code, what else you want. do not worry much, All you can do that encapsulate the whole logic in a class

Comment: @paritosh - on Code Review it is OK, and encouraged, to put up answers that say "This code is good, and this is why: ....". This has been discussed on meta: [What to do with good code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/964/31503)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your conditions, there's no way around the if-else statements. You have to enforce the conditions somehow.

Instead of if-else, another option is a `switch` statement, but the outcome is essentially the same:

```
switch (true) {
    case Math.round(e.gamma) === 0:
        value = 0;
        break;
    case e.gamma < -2:
        value = -2;
        break;
    case e.gamma > 2:
        value = 2;
        break;
    default:
        value = 99;
}
```

Comment: But somehow I find switch-case sexier - it has less curly braces :]

Comment: I actually used a `switch` statement just like this before settling on the `if`/`else if` block. It's basically what made me wonder if there was a best way to do it.